# USB data destroyed after trying to access it on iMac

Tags: windows-10, usb-flash-drive, imac

I have to use an iMac at my new job. I backed up all my files from my last job on a USB drive that was perfectly working on Windows. I made the mistake to trusting that my information would be safe and accessible on the iMac. It mounted fine and I was able to click on the drive icon but it would show an empty drive. I bring it home to my PC and everything was corrupted and it added some folders. 
Is there anyway to repair this? I looked at Recuva but it's finding large gibberish files over a gigabyte in size and it can't find the files I really need. It doesn't do a full recover.

[image: Capture of flash drive on windows]

Comment: In that same case I used Recuva. Try to use it in deep scan mode and wait for long 2h.

Comment: Maybe I just need to read the docs more. I thought I did do a deep scan but it only took 15 minutes. I'll try some more stuff